# How to find a multiple eigenvalue of a square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplace-expansion

$$
\ A=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 5 & -2 & -2 \\
-2 & 3 & 3 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

For this matrix, I am supposed to figure out which eigenvalue is a multiple eigenvalue. The answer to the problem is -1, but I am struggling to understand how to get to that conclusion.

I know that for upper or lower triangular matrices, you can find the eigenvalues just by looking at the diagonal values, but that can't happen in this case since there's a single value preventing it from being triangular at (3,4).

I also know that this can be done by finding $ det(A-\lambda I) $ and then using cofactor expansion, but since this question is taken from a past linear algebra exam at my university, I feel like there has to be a less tedious way of going about it.

Is there a simpler way to come to an answer of -1?

Comment: @Dave row operations change the eigenvaleus

Comment: The eigenvalues are $2$, $-1$ and the eigenvalues of $$\begin{bmatrix}-2&-2\\3&5\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: @Dave good point.  I answered as you indicate

Comment: @Dave thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $\det(A-\lambda I)$ is not that tedious as you thought.

$$
\begin{align*}
\det(A-\lambda I) & =
\begin{vmatrix}
2-\lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1-\lambda & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 5 & -2-\lambda & -2 \\
-2 & 3 & 3 & 5-\lambda
\end{vmatrix} \\
& =-(-2)
\begin{vmatrix}
2-\lambda & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1-\lambda & 0 \\
-2 & 3 & 3
\end{vmatrix}
+(5-\lambda)
\begin{vmatrix}
2-\lambda & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1-\lambda & 0 \\
3 & 5 & -2-\lambda
\end{vmatrix} \\
& =-(-2)(2-\lambda)(-1-\lambda)(3)+(5-\lambda)(2-\lambda)(-1-\lambda)(-2-\lambda) \\
& =(2-\lambda)(-1-\lambda)[-(-2)(3)+(5-\lambda)(-2-\lambda)] \\
& =(\lambda-2)(\lambda+1)(\lambda^2-3\lambda-4) \\
& =(\lambda-2)(\lambda+1)^2(\lambda-4)
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I didn't think to expand on column 4 to make the minors triangular. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is the square of zeroes in the upper right. That says that eigenvectors are $(1,0,0,0)^T$ and $(0,1,0,0)^T$ and then two vectors of type
$(0,0,p,q)^T$ and $(0,0,r,s)^T$ where the nonzero portions are eigenvectors of the lower right two by two, as written in comment by Dave. The characteristic polynomial for Dave's square is $\lambda^2 - 3 \lambda - 4= ( \lambda + 1)(\lambda - 4)$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-2 & -2 \\
3 & 5 
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: I understand the significance of the square of zeros now- much appreciated.